# "UnicodeDecodeError" al inicir el shell de python en el cmd de Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, shell, unicode

Buen día, tengo un problema al inicializar el shell de python en el cmd de Windows, hace menos de un día funcionaba perfectamente, pero de repente, al querer iniciar el shell de Python dentro del cmd de Windows con el comando "python", me muestra lo siguiente:

```
C:\Users\nombreusuario>python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nombreusuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site.py", line 419, in register_readline
    readline.read_history_file(history)
  File "C:\Users\nombreusuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 165, in read_history_file
    self.mode._history.read_history_file(filename)
  File "C:\Users\nombreusuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\history.py", line 82, in read_history_file
    for line in open(filename, 'r'):
  File "C:\Users\nombreusuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1932: character maps to <undefined>
>>>
```

Y como pueden ver, al final puedo utilizar el shell de Python, pero es obvio que hay un fallo, ¿Saben cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: desintala e installa la version mas reciente!

Comment: Jajajaja, ¿Es enserio?

Comment: tienes como 28 release atras van por la 3.7 :D

Comment: ¿Y para mantener los packages que tengo como le puedo hacer?

Comment: pip freeze > all_package.txt para crear un txt con todos los packetes, luego cuando terminas de instalar pip install -r all_package.txt

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que necesites reinstalar nada. Tienes la versión 3.5 que, aunque no es la última, no es ni mucho menos obsoleta. La versión 3.7 tiene cosas nuevas como las f-strings que están muy bien, pero si reinstalar te resulta un transtorno, prueba antes lo siguiente.

El problema te aparece porque Python, *en modo interactivo* (y sólo en este caso) carga el módulo `readline` para que la experiencia de usuario sea más amigable, pues te permite recuperar comandos, editarlos con mayor comodidad, autocompletar con TAB, etc.

El problema en tu caso es que `readline` conserva un histórico de comandos que hayas dado en sesiones previas, y lo guarda en un fichero de usuario. Cada vez que inicias un nuevo intérprete Python, se lee ese fichero para que puedas recuperar comandos de sesiones anteriores. En algún momento en tu fichero se introdujo un caracter raro que ahora no puede decodificar correctamente y por eso rompe.

Simplemente borra ese fichero de historia. Si no me equivoco, deberías encontrarlo en tu carpeta de usuario, con el nombre `.python_history`. Si no sabes cuál es tu carpeta de usuario puedes probar a ejecutar el comando siguiente:

```
python -c "import os; print(os.path.expanduser('~'))"
```

Comment: muchas gracias, el problema es que sigo sin encontrar ese archivo que dices, no se encuentra en la carpeta de usuario